# Resetting Android step counter

Tags: android, android-sensors

I need to reset the android step counter on button click. I know while the sensor is activated, the value will keep increasing without resetting to zero until the system is rebooted.

I have tried this but it only displays 0;

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        stepsAtReset = prefs.getInt("stepsAtReset", 0);

btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                isPaused = false;
                isStopped = false;
                activityRunning = true;

                //Disable the start and pause button
                btnStart.setEnabled(false);
                btnResume.setEnabled(false);
                //Enabled the pause and stop button
                btnPause.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(true);

                stepsAtReset = stepsInSensor;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putInt("stepsAtReset", stepsAtReset);
                editor.commit();
                // you can now display 0:
                count.setText(String.valueOf(0));

            }
        });


   @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (isPaused || isStopped) {
            Log.d("MAINFRAG", "pause or stopped");

        } else{
            if(activityRunning){
                count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
                int stepsSinceReset = stepsInSensor - stepsAtReset;

                count.setText(String.valueOf(stepsSinceReset));
            }else{
                event.values[0] = 0;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: look at this [Step Detector Usage and Reset The Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63722936/9145668), I have used that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to save your data in pref, then you need to reset your var to zero         `

```
            editor.commit();
            stepsAtReset = 0
            count.setText(String.valueOf(stepsAtReset));`
```

Comment: No, resetting the variable to zero will not meet the need.  What the variable actually needs to be set to the is the current count of the non-resettable counter.  Then the variable is subtracted from that to give a useful answer.