# How to reset a step counter?

Tags: android

I am creating a very minimalistic fitness application for a university assignment that makes use of the Google Maps API and the Android step detector sensors.

The issue I cannot resolve is how to reset the step counter to 0. I have read the documentation on Android's site and understand the counter does not get reset until the device is rebooted. I have read the previously asked questions about setting an initial value when the program is first started, but do not exactly understand what is being said. Furthermore, I've read into SharedPreferences, but do not have any experience using them.

What I wish to do is simply reset the steps to 0 using an onClickListener in conjunction with a button. Below is the code I have thus far:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    TextView steps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.step_taken);

    if(isRunning){
        steps.setText(String.valueOf(sensorEvent.values[0]));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}

public void stopSteps(){
    SensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Step counter has been deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void startSteps(){
    Sensor StepSensor = SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    SensorManager.registerListener(this, StepSensor, android.hardware.SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Step counter has been activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isRunning = true;
    Sensor StepSensor = SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if(StepSensor != null){
        SensorManager.registerListener(this, StepSensor, android.hardware.SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No sensor has been found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Is there a simple of way of implementing a reset feature? I'm almost out of time, and really stuck with this. If anyone can provide any insight with a code example, I would be very grateful. 
Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: The point is that you *cannot* reset it.  Instead write your program to have a count of the pre-existing steps which you subtract form the reading, and make your button update the pre-existing steps count to the current steps count so that the difference is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look into `SharedPreferences`. The value you're getting from `sensorEvent.values[0]` is immutable by you, so you want to be able to store that value yourself somewhere and `SharedPreferences` is by far the easiest way that persists over configuration changes.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reset sensorEvent.values[0] to 0, There is just one solution for that is to reboot your device which is mentioned in [Google Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER). But the best way to do the step counting in your app use the StepDetector sensor. It is just a suggestion :). You can easily reset counting steps using StepDetecor. I am using it in my application and it is giving accurate counting of steps.

in OnCreate Method initialize Sensors like that.

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if(sensorManager == null){
        stopSelf();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sensor not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Sensor accel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
        if(accel!=null){
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry Sensor is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

And in the onSensorChanged Method you can use this.

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
        numSteps++;
        saveSteps(numSteps);
    }
}
```

in the "saveSteps" method i am doing:

```
editor = StepsCountingPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString("WalkingSteps", String.valueOf(numSteps));
    editor.apply();
```

For Resetting the Steps Code:

```
editor.putString("WalkingSteps","0");
            editor.apply();
            tv_steps.setText(String.valueOf(0));
            numSteps=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Shared Preferences when you are using STEP_DETECTOR sensor as this sensor resets the number of steps counted to zero when ever it(app) is opened.